# CSS fixed div 100% left of own element

Tags: css, css-position, margin

I have a html/css with a div. **I want it to pull 100% of its own width.** Now it pulls 100% of the screen.

In the long run I will add a css animation on top.

https://jsfiddle.net/5L7a5pfr/

**html**

```
<div class="test left">
testing something
</div>
```

**css**

```
.test {
  position: fixed;
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.left {
  left: -100%;
}
```

Comment: i dont see anything in the jsfiddle

Comment: @MaciejWójcik I told you so, it's 100% off the screen to the left.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `transform: translateX(-100%)`

```css
.test {
  position: fixed;
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 50%;
}
.move {
  top: 25px;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="test left">testing something</div>
<div class="test left move">Move 100% left of its own width</div>
```

Comment: Was playing with your answer and think I came up with how to center it https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/5L7a5pfr/1/

Comment: I meant if he wanted to keep his centered while using your method to offset by 100% width of self.